# Calling my API with GetAsync never returns a response even though the API does

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API with a companion app that makes calls to it. I made a class library to handle the api calls (I have a feedback for logging requests) which looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string apiCall, HttpClient 
client)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiCall);

        timer.Stop();
        ApiResponseLogging.PostTimeTaken(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, apiCall, client);
        return response;
    }
```

Which is called by a main class file like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string apiCall)
    {
        ApiGet get = new ApiGet();
        return get.GetAsync(apiCall, client).Result;
    }
```

So my syntax for making an API call from within my client app is:

```
API api = new API();
var response = api.Get("api call")
```

I've made a simple APITester app that just references this class library for testing inputs (I use protobuf so postman doesn't work). When I try to use the above 2 lines of code within the test app (changing "api call" to an actual call), it gets a response immediately, however when I use the exact same 2 lines within my client app it never gets a response.

To add to the confusion:

Logging on the API & using breakpoints show the API does return the correct object, it just never gets received by this particular app.
Even when I shut down the api so there's nothing there for the GetAsync() to get from, I don't get a connection refused, or empty object, it still just sends the Get() request and never does anything after that point

Comment: `Get(string apiCall)` should be async too.

Comment: Calling `.Result` directly is almost always the wrong approach.  Make your asynchronous operations `async` and `await` them.

Comment: Using `.Result` or any of the other possible ways of getting the result is open to deadlocks.  It's best to not mix and match sync and async in this way.

Comment: async all the way down https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Thanks guys, changed my code so that Get() is also async, and the .result is only used once the response has been returned to the client, not as part of the class library itself, seems to all be working now